# Android Error,Buffer not large enough for pixels

Tags: android

```
public Bitmap getScreenCap() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[100 * 1024 * 1024];
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(100 * 1024 * 1024);

    Process exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c /system/bin/screencap -p");

    final InputStream inputStream = exec.getInputStream();
    BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
    buffer.setLength(0);
    int count;
    while ((count = bufferedInputStream.read(tempBuffer)) > 0) {
        buffer.append(new String(tempBuffer, 0, count, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
    }
    bufferedInputStream.close();
    final int retCode = exec.waitFor();
    exec.destroy();
    tempBuffer = buffer.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
    Bitmap stitchBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(3120, 1440, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    stitchBmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(ByteBuffer.wrap(tempBuffer));
    return stitchBmp;
}
```

This is my code. I am on the Android P system. I always get this error.

*java.lang.RuntimeException: Buffer not large enough for pixels*

How should I modify the buffer size?

Comment: cannot you use `Bitmap.setPixels`?

Comment: @pskink How can I use it?

Comment: so did you see the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#setPixels(int[],%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int))? if so, whats unclear?

Comment: @pskink But I don't know how to get pixels array. Sorry

Comment: you need `Bitmap#setPixels` method, not `Bitmap#getPixels`

Comment: But I only have a byte array, so should I convert it to an int array? @pskink

Comment: yes, you should - where did you get that byte array from? cannot you change this piece of code to produce int array directly?

Comment: where did you get that byte array from? whats the format of those raw bytes?

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c /system/bin/screencap -p")

Comment: @pskink I had updated my code

Comment: so you need `BitmapFactory#decodeByteArray` becaose your byte data is not raw pixels, but encoded png bytes